# Problems creating an update.zip that works in AOSP recovery

Tags: android, edify

I'm trying to create an update zip that works in stock (AOSP) recovery on Android on a Nexus 4.

I'm creating an update.zip that contains an Edify script, and signing the whole thing using `sinapk.jar` and the platform keys that were generated with my AOSP build.

However, the zip is rejected when I try to deploy it through `adb sideload`.

```
Verifying update package...
Installation aborted
```

What would I be doing wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful to pull the recovery.log from the device. In the code the progression you describe would dump from the zip failing verification. (see the bode in bootable/recovery/recovery.cpp and install.cpp). Beyond that it's tough to know exactly what is happening.